# How to strip multiple unwanted characters from a list of strings in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have the following input string:

```
text='''Although never is often better than *right* now.

If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.

Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!'''
```

So far, I have split the `text` string into a `list` like so:

```
list=['Although', 'never', 'is', 'often', 'better', 'than', '*right*', 'now.\n\nIf', 'the', 'implementation', 'is', 'hard', 'to', 'explain,', "it's", 'a', 'bad', 'idea.\n\nIf', 'the', 'implementation', 'is', 'easy', 'to', 'explain,', 'it', 'may', 'be', 'a', 'good', 'idea.\n\nNamespaces', 'are', 'one', 'honking', 'great','idea', '--', "let's", 'do', 'more', 'of', 'those!']
```

Now, I want to use `strip` function to remove unwanted characters such as `\n\n` and `--` from the above list.

Can You please help me on this??

Comment: `stripped = list(map(str.strip,old_list))`

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried.

Comment: What were your thoughts so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re` module, [`re.sub`](https://kite.com/python/docs/re.sub) function will allow you to do that.
We need to replace multilpe `\n` occurences with single `\n` and remove `--` string

```
import re

code='''Although never is often better than right now.

If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.

Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!'''


result = re.sub('\n{2,}', '\n', code)
result = re.sub(' -- ', ' ', result)

print(result)
```

After that split() your text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can i know what {2,} in the `result = re.sub('\n**{2,}**', '\n', code)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will split the string with either space or newline character

```
import re

output = [i for i in re.split(r'\s|\n{1:2}|--', code) if i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to get rid of `--`

```
>>> code='''Although never is often better than right now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!'''
>>> 
>>> [word for word in code.split() if word != '--']
['Although', 'never', 'is', 'often', 'better', 'than', 'right', 'now.', 'If', 'the', 'implementation', 'is', 'hard', 'to', 'explain,', "it's", 'a', 'bad', 'idea.', 'If', 'the', 'implementation', 'is', 'easy', 'to', 'explain,', 'it', 'may', 'be', 'a', 'good', 'idea.', 'Namespaces', 'are', 'one', 'honking', 'great', 'idea', "let's", 'do', 'more', 'of', 'those!']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sunitha. But im actually looking to remove multiple characters in a single attempt.. Like "--,\n,!,." mentioned should wipe off from my result. Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: `{2,}` means "2 or more". So if there are sequences like \n\n, \n\n\n, ..., \n\n...\n all they will be replaced by single \n